# How to assert the new activity has been started

Tags: android

In my unit test (which extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<>`) I need to assert the new activity has been started. I do it like this but on the last line execution just hangs.

```
public void testNewActivityLaunched() throws Throwable {
        TouchUtils.clickView(this, mButton); // starting new activity here

        String actualActivityName = getActivity().getClass().getName().toString();
        String expectedActiviyName = "my.package.com";
        assertEquals(actualActivityName, expectedActiviyName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create ActivityMonitors and add them to the instrumentation.Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html.